# How to add dynamic content in splashscreen of ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, dynamic-splash-screen

In my ionic 3 application, i want to add dynamic content in splash screen so that i can show current version of my application in the splash screen, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen is static image and you can't add there any dynamic values.
Te simplest way is just add app version in footer or about page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that with using HTML and CSS

Navigate to the default page that loads when your app launches. In our case, this is located in: /src/pages/home.html

At the top of **home.html** just above  paste in:

```
<div id="custom-overlay" [style.display]="splash ? 'flex': 'none'">
  <div class="flb">
    <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--top"></div>
    <img src="assets/logo.svg">
    <div class="Aligner-item Aligner-item--bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The #custom-overlay div will cover the entire screen. We're using style binding set to a CSS display property. If the splash property is true, it will set it to flex, if not, it will set it to none .

The .flb class and everything inside of it is optional.

The Splash CSS: Within the **home.scss** file, paste in:

```
#custom-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #002a3e;
}

.flb {
  background-color: #3ebffb;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  animation: pulse 1s linear forwards;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.Aligner-item {
  max-width: 50%;
}
.Aligner-item--top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.Aligner-item--bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
#custom-overlay img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  animation: animation 3100ms linear infinite both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

The key ingredient here is #custom-overlay. The associated CSS ruleset makes it cover the current page. Anything else within it is up to you and the needs of your splash page.

You can visit these **links** for more information on how to use this in your project:
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/51/How-to-Make-an-Animated-Ionic-Splash-Page-with-HTML-&-CSS113 
https://github.com/Flink91/ionic2-animated-splashscreen92